# Displaying blank content in gxt tab panel instead of pdf content

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have to display PDF content in a GXT tab panel. But it is displayed as a blank page in a tab. When I use window.open using the same URL, PDF is opened in a browser. Can you please help me in resolving this. Find the code below.

```
Frame frame = new Frame("path to the url/"+fileName);
return frame;
```

And I am adding the frame to the tab panel as below

```
TabItemConfig tabConfig = new TabItemConfig(loadedView.getLabel(), true);
tabPanel.add(frame, tabConfig);
```

Comment: Any errors in console ? is the pdf loading from different domain ?

Comment: No errors found in the console. The same PDF is opened in a window using com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(userId + "/" + fileName, "", "width=1028,height=720");. But it is not getting loaded in the tabpanel.

Comment: is the pdf loading from different domain ?

Comment: Have you tried to give the frame a size? -> frame.setSize("100%", "100%");

Comment: Yes. But still it did not work @ElHoss. And when i inspected the blank element in firebug, i got the xml format which says nothing is there in iFrame.<iframe class="gwt-Frame" style="width: 901px; height: 630px;">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>

Comment: Just added a tab to a TabPanel which contains a frame that loads a pdf and it works really nice., So, I would check the url. Do you load the pdf from another server? (SOP)

Comment: That's what ATTA already suggested.

Comment: I am loading the file from the server where the project is running. @ElHoss. I have created a small application to load one pdf from desktop. But even this is not working. Am i giving the right slash(\\) ?Frame frame = new     Frame("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\1.pdf");RootPanel.get("labelContainer").add(frame);

Comment: this will not work, because you can not load a pdf from the client storage., Load the pdf from the server. Add the pdf to the war/wepapp folder and load the pdf with http://localost:port...'

Comment: Thank you @ElHoss. It worked :)